Справка по Eclipse RCP в браузере
У меня есть приложение RCP, к которому я прикрепил свой плагин справки. Справка открывается, когда я нажимаю кнопку Open Help, а затем открывается новое окно со справкой. Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы мой плагин справки открывался в окне браузера?
Мой plugin.xml от плагина справки:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.toc">
         <toc file="toc_Concepts.xml" />
         <toc file="toc_Ref.xml" />
         <toc file="toc_Tasks.xml" />
      <toc
            file="toc.xml">
      </toc>
      <toc
            file="testToc.xml"
            primary="true">
      </toc>
   </extension>
      <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.displayHelp"
               label="Open Help"
               tooltip="Open the Eclipse Help System">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>

